# Subscribe to Firebird events using a Jdbc driver for connection?

Tags: events, jdbc, firebird, jaybird, b4j

I am writing an application in a B4J environment with data connection on Firebird.

https://www.b4x.com/b4j.html

B4J uses the Firebird Jdbc driver for communication between the application and the db server. I would need to link the application code to 'events' generated by triggers defined on Firebird. How to do, from code B4J, to subscribe to Firebird 'events'?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Is an answer in Java code to subscribe to events sufficient, or are you looking for a b4j specific answer?

Comment: I need B4J code (very similar to VB code) to subscribe a Firebird events.  B4J development system can use Jdbc driver, and at link   https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#_database_events   is available an example of code to do that, unfortunately is no code for B4J, so what I am looking for is the conversion of this code to make it work in the B4J environment

Comment: I'm one of the maintainers of Jaybird. That part of the Jaybird driver has nothing to do with the JDBC API, so I guess you can't use the JDBC support B4J has, and I assume you will need to be able to call Java code from B4J to use it. Having no knowledge of B4J, I can't help you with that.

Comment: https://www.b4x.com/guides/B4xJavaObject_NativeObject/?page=6 says "JavaObject can be used to access Android or Java objects or properties not directly exposed to B4A or B4J. The library is the same for B4A and B4J."